# Removing lines in my file that contain a certain variable in python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, startswith

My test.txt looks like

```
bear
goat
cat
```

what im trying to do is take the first line of it, which is bear and find and lines that contain it then delete them, the problem here is when I run my code all it does is delete all of the contents of my output file.

```html
import linecache
must_delete = linecache.getline('Test.txt', 1)
with open('output.txt','r+') as f:
    data = ''.join([i for i in f if not i.lower().startswith(must_delete)])
    f.seek(0)                                                         
    f.write(data)                                                     
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: ```i for i in f``` is the output file.   Should be linecache.

Comment: Could you show me an example I’m very new to python

Comment: @OPP: Individual tutorials are beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is in-place editing, meaning read and write at the same time, line by line. Python has the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) module which offers this ability.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import linecache
import fileinput

must_delete = linecache.getline('Test.txt', 1)

for line in fileinput.input('output.txt', inplace=True):
    if line != must_delete:
        print(line, end='')
```

## Notes

- The calls to `fileinput.input()` includes the parameter `inplace=True` which specifies in-place editing
- Within the with block, because of the in-place editing, the `print()` function (by magic) will print to the file, not your console.
- We need to call `print()` with `end=''` to avoid extra line-ending char(s). Alternatively, we can omit the `from __future__ ...` line and do use the print statement like this (note the ending comma):

  ```
  print line,
  ```

## Update

If you want to detect the presence of the first line (e.g. 'bear') then there are two things more to do:

1. In previous code, I did not strip new line from `must_delete`, so it might looks like `bear\n`. Now we need to strip off the new line in order to test anywhere within the line
2. Instead of comparing the line with `must_delete`, we must do a partial string comparison: `if must_delete in line:`

Putting it all together:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import linecache
import fileinput

must_delete = linecache.getline('Test.txt', 1)
must_delete = must_delete.strip()  # Additional Task 1

for line in fileinput.input('output.txt', inplace=True):
    if must_delete not in line:  # Additional Task 2
        print(line, end='')
```

## Update 2

```
from __future__ import print_function
import linecache
import fileinput

must_delete = linecache.getline('Test.txt', 1)
must_delete = must_delete.strip()
total_count = 0  # Total number of must_delete found in the file

for line in fileinput.input('output.txt', inplace=True):
    # How many times must_delete appears in this line
    count = line.count(must_delete)
    if count > 0:
        print(line, end='')
    total_count += count  # Update the running total

# total_count is now the times must_delete appears in the file
# It is not the number of deleted lines because a line might contains
# must_delete more than once
```

Comment: how can think work if my output file has multiple things per line and then contains  the word"bear"

Comment: So, if the first line is 'bear', you want to remove lines with 'bear cat', 'big bear', ...?

Comment: Yes. that's exactly what im looking for

Comment: Hai Vu Yes. that's exactly what im looking for

Comment: Works great!!!!! one more thing though, i also want to count how many times the data appears in the second file. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: There is no second file, what data? I don't understand your question. Would you please explain?

Comment: In the linecache.getline was my input file  and the fileinput.input was my second file, im also trying to count how many times the first line appears in my second file

Comment: I encountered a problem with this script, it deletes the entire contents of the file instead of the specified parts of it

Answer (score 0):

1. You read a variable `must_delete`, but you parse with `mustdelete`.
2. You walk through the output file (i for i in f); I think you want to scan the input.
3. You truncate the file at the given location; are you sure that's what you want to do *inside* the loop?

Comment: What loop are you referring to?